# Awkward Date Related Query in R/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Have a tricky query I'm trying to run on a data set (~200k rows) with lots of date fields.

A pared down reprex would be like this:

```
df <- data.frame(index          = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 effective_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-06-13", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-04-13", "2025-01-01", "2025-03-01", "2026-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")),
                 end_date       = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", NA, "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2025-01-01", NA, "2026-01-01", NA, "2027-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01")),
                 type           = c("normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "normal", "normal"))
```

Logic as follows:

The `end_date` for all records where `type` = `"SPECIAL"` is unknown and needs to be calculated.

Calculate as follows: for each record where `type` = `"SPECIAL"`

retrieve the `end_date` for the `"normal"` records (for that particular `index` value)
pick the **earliest** `end_date` from that list which is still >= `effective_date` for the `"SPECIAL"` record.

This would give the following results:

```
df_2 <- data.frame(index          = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                   effective_date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-06-13", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-04-13", "2025-01-01", "2025-03-01", "2026-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")),
                   end_date       = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", NA, "2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2025-01-01", NA, "2026-01-01", NA, "2027-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01")),
                   type           = c("normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "SPECIAL", "normal", "normal", "normal"),
                   calc_end_date  = as.Date(c(NA, "2021-01-01", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2025-01-01", NA, "2026-01-01", NA, NA, NA)))
```

(constructed this dummy data by hand and I'm tired - I hope I didn't make any mistakes!)

I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this using `dplyr` type functions (I like `dplyr`), but I'm not an expert and I'm struggling to see how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: This will get much simpler with the upcoming dplyr 1.1, currently available as development version on github, since it includes non-equi joins. Are you open to solution with the dev version?

Comment: Possibly…haven’t done it before (dev versions of packages that is) but I’m open to trying it out if it means a nice tidy solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` 1.0.99.9000, we can take the `SPECIAL` rows and join them to the closest non-`SPECIAL` row with same index and equal or later end_date.

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")

updates <- left_join(df %>% filter(type == "SPECIAL"),
                     df %>% filter(type != "SPECIAL"), 
                     join_by(index, closest(effective_date <= end_date))) %>%
  # extract just the columns we want to join
  select(index, effective_date = effective_date.x, calc_end_date = end_date.y) 
  
df %>%
  left_join(updates)
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(index, effective_date)`
   index effective_date   end_date    type calc_end_date
1      1     2020-01-01 2021-01-01  normal          <NA>
2      1     2020-06-13       <NA> SPECIAL    2021-01-01
3      1     2021-01-01 2022-01-01  normal          <NA>
4      1     2022-01-01 2023-01-01  normal          <NA>
5      2     2023-01-01 2024-01-01  normal          <NA>
6      2     2024-01-01 2025-01-01  normal          <NA>
7      2     2024-04-13       <NA> SPECIAL    2025-01-01
8      2     2025-01-01 2026-01-01  normal          <NA>
9      2     2025-03-01       <NA> SPECIAL    2026-01-01
10     2     2026-01-01 2027-01-01  normal          <NA>
11     3     2015-01-01 2016-01-01  normal          <NA>
12     3     2016-01-01 2017-01-01  normal          <NA>
```

---

The "updates" table could be created less efficiently with dplyr <1.1 using a cartesian join followed by filtering. This can be fine for small data, but could explode inefficiently if there are many observations per index.

```
left_join(df %>% filter(type == "SPECIAL"),
          df %>% filter(type != "SPECIAL"), 
          by = c("index")) %>%
  arrange(index, effective_date.x, end_date.y) %>%
  group_by(index, effective_date.x) %>%
  filter(end_date.y >= effective_date.x) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(index, effective_date = effective_date.x, calc_end_date = end_date.y) %>%
  ungroup() -> updates
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting bit of code (and nice & short). Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: Afterthought: join_by() is of great interest to me - specifically the overlap joins (I’ve just briefly read the documentation). I do these often in quite a roundabout way - I think this would be a lot cleaner. Interesting 

Comment: dplyr 1.0.99.9000 install done - your code works! Thank you. Now to (a) understand it and (b) adapt it to my actual big data frame. Need another cup of coffee first...